# Publish C# program to Azure - not succeed

Tags: c#, azure

I new to Azure. I have a program written in C#, I need to change it and publish it to Azure.

When I tried to publish it, I got this error:

> Publish Started
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(750,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'BillingAzure.csproj'.
>   Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.
>   Configuration='Release' Platform='Any CPU'.
>   You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [\path\to\dir\BillingAzure.csproj]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set an `OutputPath` in the project setup? Usually you output to "bin"

Comment: What kind of project are we talking about? What Azure Service are you deploying to?

Comment: Please share the BillingAzure.csproj code

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it's happening because you directly opened the .csproj file.

Suggestions:

- Open the  csproj file and save the solution file (*.sln)
- Open the sln file and select the configuration for release
- Make sure you can build it and try publishing it your local filesystem first to make sure it works without errors.
- Once all these work, you should be able to publish to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that "**AnyCPU**" **does not contain any space** wherever you are using in your build definition.

You could update the following code in Properties\PublishProfiles\ProfileName>.pubxml:

`<LastUsedPlatform>AnyCPU</LastUsedPlatform>`

You could refer to this related [link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/571).